# postgresql combining several periods into one

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, range

I'm trying to combine range.

```
WITH a AS (
select '2017-09-16 07:12:57' as begat,'2017-09-16 11:30:22' as endat
union 
select '2017-09-18 17:05:21' ,'2017-09-19 13:18:01'
union 
select '2017-09-19 15:34:40' ,'2017-09-22 13:29:37'
union 
select '2017-09-22 12:24:16' ,'2017-09-22 13:18:29' 
union 
select '2017-09-28 09:48:54' ,'2017-09-28 13:39:13'
union 
select '2017-09-20 13:52:43' ,'2017-09-20 14:14:43' 
  ), b AS (
   SELECT *, lag(endat) OVER (ORDER BY begat) < begat OR NULL AS step
   FROM   a
   )
, c AS (
   SELECT *, count(step) OVER (ORDER BY begat) AS grp
   FROM   b
   )
SELECT min(begat), coalesce( max(endat), 'infinity' ) AS range
FROM   c
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY 1
```

Result

```
   1 "2017-09-16 07:12:57";"2017-09-16 11:30:22"
   2 "2017-09-18 17:05:21";"2017-09-19 13:18:01"
   3 "2017-09-19 15:34:40";"2017-09-22 13:29:37"
   4 "2017-09-22 12:24:16";"2017-09-22 13:18:29"
   5 "2017-09-28 09:48:54";"2017-09-28 13:39:13"
```

positions 3,4 intersect (endata> next begat)
How do I make the union of all the intersections into one large interval

I need result

```
   1 "2017-09-16 07:12:57";"2017-09-16 11:30:22"
   2 "2017-09-18 17:05:21";"2017-09-19 13:18:01"
   3 "2017-09-19 15:34:40";"2017-09-22 13:29:37"
   4 "2017-09-28 09:48:54";"2017-09-28 13:39:13"
```

Comment: "postgresql combining several periods into one" Define period.. looking into "positions 3,4 intersect (endata> next begat)" and "  3 "2017-09-19 15:34:40";"2017-09-22 13:29:37"
   4 "2017-09-22 12:24:16";"2017-09-22 13:18:29""  it looks look a "period" is the same endat day..

Comment: Not sure because untested but `GROUP  BY grp, EXTRACT(DATE FROM a.endat)` might do the trick here.

Comment: i did it  ` WITH tmp AS (
 select  begat, coalesce( endat, 'infinity' ) as endAt, tsrange( begat, coalesce( endat, 'infinity' ) ) as rg
 from (
.... time range...
 ) a
  ),a as (
    select l.*
      from tmp l left join tmp r on  l.begAt > r.begAt and r.rg @>  l.rg
      where r.begAt is null  
  ),
  b AS (
   SELECT *, lag(endat) OVER (ORDER BY begat) < begat OR NULL AS step
   FROM   a
   )
, c AS (
   SELECT *, count(step) OVER (ORDER BY begat) AS grp
   FROM   b
   )
SELECT min(begat), coalesce( max(endat), 'infinity' ) AS range
FROM   c
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY 1 `

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - [edit] your question instead0

Answer (score 1):

Hey I would suggest using the following process :

1- Identify when a row is new, so you give a value of 1 to values that do not overlap (CTE b)

2- Sequence together the rows that have overlaps with others. This way you can see have a common identifier that will allow you to MAX and MIN begat and endat (CTE c)

3- For each sequence, give the MIN of begat and the MAX of endat so you will have your final values

```
WITH a AS (
select '2017-09-16 07:12:57' as begat,'2017-09-16 11:30:22' as endat
union 
select '2017-09-18 17:05:21' ,'2017-09-19 13:18:01'
union 
select '2017-09-19 15:34:40' ,'2017-09-22 13:29:37'
union 
select '2017-09-22 12:24:16' ,'2017-09-22 13:18:29' 
union 
select '2017-09-28 09:48:54' ,'2017-09-28 13:39:13'
union 
select '2017-09-20 13:52:43' ,'2017-09-20 14:14:43' 
  )
, b AS (
SELECT
    begat
  , endat
  , (begat > MAX(endat) OVER w IS TRUE)::INT is_new
FROM a
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY begat ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
) 
, c AS (
SELECT
    begat
  , endat
  , SUM((is_new)) OVER (ORDER BY begat) seq
FROM b
)
SELECT
    MIN(begat) beg_at
  , MAX(endat) end_at
FROM c
GROUP BY seq
```

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer, this solution should be much faster than any recursive solution for any significant volume of data.

Comment: I accidentaly delete my comment. I sayd that I doubt about eficiency looking at the SUM. It like to be O(n^2), the recursive solution it is like O(n)

Comment: @HaleemurAli, you are right. Your version is over 1000 times better than the recursive with select and over 10 times better than the psql version for this example and few records. But, allways are a size that over that size the O(n) is better. In my solution I put a sentence to insert years of rows. In my machine with 400,000 rows the O(n) psql version start to work, fast.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

If you need speed you can use a psql function:

```
create or replace function append_ranges_in_a() returns setof a
  language plpgsql
as
$BODY$
declare
  v_current a%rowtype;
  v_new a%rowtype;
  v_first boolean:=true;
begin
  for v_current in select begat, endat from a order by begat, endat
  loop
    if v_first then
      v_first := false;
      v_new.begat := v_current.begat;
    elsif v_new.endat < v_current.begat then
      return next v_new;
      v_new.begat := v_current.begat;
    end if;
    v_new.endat := greatest(v_current.endat,v_new.endat);
  end loop;
  return next v_new;
  return;
end;
$BODY$;

select * from append_ranges_in_a()
```

I test it with ~ 400000 rows:

```
delete from a;

insert into a (begat,  endat)
  select time::text, (time+'1 day'::interval)::text
    from (select t+(round(random()*23.0)||' hours')::interval as time
       from generate_series('1401-01-01'::timestamp,'2018-08-21'::timestamp,'1 day'::interval) t
    ) t;

select count(*) from a;

select * from append_ranges_in_a() offset 100000 limit 10
```

and it is twice fast as O(n^2) pure SQL version.

**OLD slow solution:**

You can use a recursive WITH query https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html to construct the result row by row.

1. I create the table
2. The first row is the candidate first row (ending where ending), but the row is not "ready"
3. Then I look at the next row (step) and if it is not intersecting I add a ready row,
4. Also I add a not ready row with the current (last) observed range
5. When I do not have more rows I calculate the last row
6. I retain ready rows and the last row

Here is the code

```
CREATE TABLE a as 
select '2017-09-16 07:12:57' as begat,'2017-09-16 11:30:22' as endat
union 
select '2017-09-18 17:05:21' ,'2017-09-19 13:18:01'
union 
select '2017-09-19 15:34:40' ,'2017-09-22 13:29:37'
union 
select '2017-09-22 12:24:16' ,'2017-09-22 13:18:29' 
union 
select '2017-09-28 09:48:54' ,'2017-09-28 13:39:13'
union 
select '2017-09-20 13:52:43' ,'2017-09-20 14:14:43';

WITH RECURSIVE t(begat, endat, ready, step) AS (
    select * from (
      select *,false,1 from a order by begat, endat limit 1) a
  UNION ALL
    SELECT new_rows.*
       FROM (SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY begat DESC limit 1) t,
           lateral (SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY begat, endat OFFSET step LIMIT 1) a,
           lateral (
              SELECT t.begat, t.endat, true as ready, step WHERE t.endat < a.begat
              UNION SELECT CASE WHEN t.endat < a.begat THEN a.begat ELSE t.begat END, greatest(a.endat, t.endat), false, step+1
           ) new_rows
)
select begat, endat
  from (
   select begat, endat, ready, row_number() over (order by begat desc, endat desc)=1 is_last
     from t
     order by begat, endat) t
  where ready or is_last;
```

Answer (score 0):

i using range type
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html

```
    WITH tmp AS (
         -- preparation range type
        select  begat, coalesce( endat, 'infinity' ) as endAt, tsrange( begat, coalesce( endat, 'infinity' ) ) as rg
        from (
        select '2017-09-11 17:13:03'::timestamp as begat ,'2017-09-12 12:24:09'::timestamp as endat  union
        select '2017-09-19 15:34:40','2017-09-20 11:04:45' union
        select '2017-09-20 08:32:00','2017-09-22 13:28:37' union
        select '2017-09-20 13:52:43','2017-09-20 14:14:43' union
        select '2017-09-21 12:24:16','2017-09-21 13:28:29' union
        select '2017-09-22 12:24:16','2017-09-22 13:28:29' union
        select '2017-09-22 12:34:16','2017-09-23 13:28:29' union
        select '2017-09-22 12:25:16','2017-09-24 13:28:29' union
        select '2017-09-28 09:48:54','2017-09-28 13:39:13' union
        select '2017-09-28 14:22:16','2017-09-28 15:52:15' union
        select '2017-10-05 12:17:45','2017-10-06 12:35:38' union
        select '2017-10-06 16:20:44','2017-10-07 10:11:09' union
        select '2017-10-07 20:38:32','2017-10-09 14:42:29' union
        select '2017-10-12 18:22:14','2017-10-12 20:52:45'

        ) a
      ),a as (
       -- group intersecting range
        select l.*
          from tmp l left join tmp r on  l.begAt > r.begAt and r.rg @>  l.rg
          where r.begAt is null  
      ),

       b AS (
       SELECT *, lag(endat) OVER (ORDER BY begat) < begat OR NULL AS step
       FROM   a
       )
    , c AS (
       SELECT *, count(step) OVER (ORDER BY begat) AS grp
       FROM   b
       )
    SELECT min(begat), coalesce( max(endat), 'infinity' ) AS range
    FROM   c
    GROUP  BY grp
    ORDER  BY 1
```

Comment: Same solution, but O(n^2). For few records work fast, but for a lot of rows you may prefer the O(n) psql version.